# How to get the exact cause for login failure in Salesforce SOAP API?

Tags: soap-api, login

I got error message like "Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out."

Is there any way I can get the exact reason for login failure?

If the password is wrong then it should return "Invalid password" not the entire message like the above

Comment: You can check the logs in User detail page.

Comment: I don't think users has access to those logs. Almost all systems that I know does not display "Invalid Password" error, even if it is actually an invalid password. It will be a huge security issue.

Comment: @SLman It does show. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

[image: Viewing the User Detail Page log can give you the insight]

You can view the user detail page log. It will give you insights.

Answer (score 0):

The message you get on the login page is very secured. You cannot modify that.
Because Salesforce ensures that any unauthorized user does not get any specific information around which field actually was incorrect.